# Android Studio 4.1 not opening in windows 7 professional 64 bits-6GB RAM

Tags: android, android-studio

[Loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJhoQ.png)  Previously I used Android Studio 2.3.3.Now I have uninstall it and install the latest version i.e. 4.1.  But, it doesn't open. I have also tried setting the environment variable path. Still can't load. Is there any solution?

Comment: Do you get any error / debug messages when opening Android Studio?

Comment: No error. Just the loading doesn't finish up.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing ctrl+R and I copy this %APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio4.1. Then I deleted everything inside the folder. After that, I restarted the PC and it works.